Where is the documentation for how ptyest implements conftest.py files?
I'm new to Python. Been playing with pytest and I'm ready to tear my hair out. As best I can tell, an older version of pytest, 7.2.2 searches up the directory tree and merges in conftest file. In 8.3.3, it only seems to find conftest.py if it's in the same directory I run the tests in.
I can't find any official documentation that spells out how pytest implements these files. This is the best I could find and it wasn't very helpful: https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.3.x/how-to/plugins.html#requiring-loading-plugins-in-a-test-module-or-conftest-file
Here's output from 7.2.2:
> $ pytest test_simple_module.py -s                                                                                         [±main ●]
CONFTEST ../../ LOADED
CONFTEST .. LOADED
CONFTEST . LOADED
======================================================== test session starts =========================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.11.10, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/steve/python/tests/TestUtils/PytestWrapper/simple_module
plugins: anyio-3.7.1
collecting ...
Collected test items:

Here's output from 8.3.3:
(test_env) > $ pytest -s test_simple_module.py                                                                                  [±main ●]
CONFTEST . LOADED
========================================================== test session starts ===========================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.12.7, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /Users/steve/python/tests/TestUtils/PytestWrapper/simple_module
collected 7 items

Notice the key difference: conftest.py's from directories higher up are loaded in 7.2.2 but only conftest.py from currently directory in 8.3.3.

This is not a duplicate. I'm trying to figure out why 8.3.3 does not load conftest file from parent directories. Jesus.

OK, answer is here: #11043: When --confcutdir is not specified, and there is no config file present, the conftest cutoff directory (--confcutdir) is now set to the rootdir. Previously in such cases, conftest.py files would be probed all the way to the root directory of the filesystem. If you are badly affected by this change, consider adding an empty config file to your desired cutoff directory, or explicitly set --confcutdir.
Whoever downvoted/closed this issue  is clueless. Change was made in 7.4.0 version of pytest.
